# How can I create a c++ console application which makes use of an open source c project

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg, visual-studio-2017

I've been playing around with a compiled version of https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg. But it has some problems, during the closing of an opened stream using `avio_close`(it takes a really long time to close it).

I've been trying to understand what could go wrong by reading through the implementation, but couldn't find anything.

What I would like to do, is to actually have a C++ console application which uses the c files and to debug them while running the code(using breakpoints and so on).

Unfortunately I cannot find any information on how to set it up. Simply copying the files in a new console application is not enough.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Edit: I can already see a closing vote. If this question is not appropriate for this website, I will delete it. But please point me in the right direction of where to post it.Although it is quite a general question, I believe that it is clear and enough information has been provided.

Edit2: Yes, I was a bit unclear about what I'm using.

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017 on Windows 10 for creating the C++ console application.

Edit3:

Steps that I've taken into using the source files into my console application which was using the DLLs.

1. Copy all of the contents of the FFmpeg-master to my console application
2. Include all of them in the c++ console application project
3. Run a build - takes forever and has infinite build errors( > 1000) - probably compiler related

Edit4:

I have no actual errors with `avio_close`, it just takes too long to close the stream. What I found out when playing around with the settings is that when the `fifo_size` parameter is set, closing the stream is a lot faster depending on how small the set value is. And it sort of makes sense since `fifo_size` is related to the packet size, but I haven't found out where in the code this size has an impact.

> fifo_size=units
>   Set the UDP receiving circular buffer size, expressed as a number of packets with size of 188 bytes. If not specified defaults to 7*4096.

Edit5: I still haven't found a way to compile the open source ffmpeg project into libs, dlls and pdbs. Am I the first one needing such files(seems unrealistic)? 
The only tool capable of delivering those so far is `vcpkg`. The only problem is that it compiles the 3.3.3 version and the latest is 4.0.2 .

I tried to modify the `vcpkg\ports\ffmpeg\portfile.cmake` file to include the latest version of ffmpeg, but it doesn't build it.

Are there any other suggestions?

Comment: Are you compiling ffmpeg yourself or using binaries compiled by someone else? it sounds like you are missing debug information for ffmpeg, and sometimes the easiest way to solve this is to compile the project yourself.

Comment: Using binaries compiled by someone else. Yes, debug information would help, but haven't found a way on how to build the project either. However stepping through the code would be ideal.

Comment: It would help if you show error messages and explain how it did not work. One of the problems in your question (by not explaining what went wrong) is you limit your question to people who have made console applications that use ffmpeg and that have had some type of problem setting it up that they remember and were able to overcome this problem. I assume since you say console that you are talking about windows and not linux and that you are using Visual Studio and not clang or gcc.

Comment: As an aside, note that `avio_close` may have to perform a lot of work depending on the stream type.  That could involve writing a lot of metadata and/or check-summing the stream data etc.  So I'm not sure there's anything *wrong* as such.

Comment: @drescherjm yes, you are correct. I should've specified what I'm using and on what operating system. I have updated the question as well.

Comment: Note that `ffmpeg` is in `vcpkg` I am testing right now under Visual Studio 2017 if it produces debug binaries. `vcpkg` looks like it builds `ffmpeg` using `mingw` even though I use VS2017, it downloaded mingw to build. I think it does build debug but it will be awhile on my 6C / 12T laptop.

Comment: Oh so you are trying to build ffmpeg using VS 2017 by putting its source code in a VS console application. I expect its more difficult than that.

Comment: @drescherjm yes, it sure is. Haven't found a way so far

Comment: It appears that `vcpkg` does create debug binaries for `ffmpeg` that probably is your best bet. https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg

Comment: It just finished building `ffmpeg`. The debug version created with `vcpkg` does include `.pdb` files with the libraries and dlls. I built the 32 bit version since `vcpkg` defaults to 32 bit ( can be changed by setting an environment variable from the command line where you run vcpkg.

Comment: Thank you. I'll have a look at `vcpkg`. I haven't used it so far. I'll keep you updated. But, as I've said, I actually need the source code, since I get no errors, it just takes longer. I'll also update with the actual `avio_close` issue. Maybe I can solve it without having to set up such a project, but it would be nice to know how to do it.

Comment: ***But, as I've said, I actually need the source code*** The source code is there with vcpkg. It builds from source and has the code in the build tree. And as I said it provides the .pdb files linking to the source. Although with that said I did not try debugging. I can't spend more time on this now, got to go to the paying job...

Comment: Haha, fair enough. But, correct me if I'm wrong, you cannot actually step through code with the pdb file. It does contain some information, but nothing close to stepping through the code. And, since I don't get any errors in my code(no exceptions see Edit4), the pdb files are not that helpful.

Comment: You are correct. I understand now. This would not be an optimal setup if you wanted to make changes to the source code. You may want to try the ubuntu approach or even install an IDE that develops using the mingw toolchain. Maybe qt-creator or clion. I know visual-studio and visual-studio code have options for other toolchains but that is more work for you to learn.

Comment: ***you cannot actually step through code with the pdb file*** I believe you should be able to do that.

Comment: Yes, I was able to do that.I can add a breakpoint on the function that I want to debug and step into it. As I understood, the pdb file stores the source file location and it uses it? Or how is the link between dll, pdb and source code achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using `vcpkg`.

As a guide for building this **specific**(as in no idea if it would work the same for others open source projects) package:

1) Download [vcpkg](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg) and go through the installation process described in the README file

2) Go to

> ..\vcpkg\ports\ffmpeg\

and edit the `portfile.cmake` file.

By default vcpkg will build the 3.3.3 version of ffmpeg and it uses

```
vcpkg_download_distfile(ARCHIVE
URLS "http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-3.3.3.tar.bz2"
FILENAME "ffmpeg-3.3.3.tar.bz2"
SHA512 1cc63bf73356f4e618c0d3572a216bdf5689f10deff56b4262f6d740b0bee5a4b3eac234f45fca3d4d2da77903a507b4fba725b76d2d2070f31b6dae9e7a2dab
)
```

Change it to

```
vcpkg_download_distfile(ARCHIVE
    URLS "http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-4.0.2.tar.bz2"
    FILENAME "ffmpeg-4.0.2.tar.bz2"
    SHA512 92a3bedcd070df72b26dbe3ebf4a3faea0a02289fbefdb6a6c73d65801cf60a7e11cd832d29ab46b7749a1ffd0a31505cf75bb46bd01ea06423b454ca04e9b7b
)
```

This will download the latest ffmpeg version. 
In order for the build to work you also have to comment these lines:

```
if("ffserver" IN_LIST FEATURES)
    set(OPTIONS "${OPTIONS} --enable-ffserver")
else()
    set(OPTIONS "${OPTIONS} --disable-ffserver")
endif()
```

I assume that since version 3.3.3 this option was removed/disabled and it doesn't work anymore.

3) Run(it will take a while)

> .\vcpkg install ffmpeg

You should now have a 4.0.2 debug and release version of FFMPEG with DLLs, PDBs, libs and includes folders.

Not entirely sure if this process was correct, but my project is working fine and I'm now able to debug it.

Answer (score 3):

There are some tools and workflows that you need to be confortable with in order to debug an application from the source code using a debugger.

First you need to know how to build the application. That is usually achieved by running:

```
$ ./configure
$ make
```

Since you want to debug, you must set some compiler flags that will instruct the compiler to produce debugging information that will be used by the debugger to relate machine instructions to the relevant lines of source code. In the case of FFMpeg, you just need to change the configure commad to:

```
$ ./configure --enable-debug
```

Please take a look at `$ configure --help` to see all the options, `configure` is extremely well documented in this project.

After running `make` you will have an executable that has debugging information, then you need to learn how to use a debugger. The `gdb` debugger is the one most used, and is actually the backend of most GUI debuggers. There are lots of informations and tutorials on how to use gdb, please do a google search for `gdb tutorial` and choose the one you find most comprehensible.

The most relevant tasks you will need to learn are how to set up breakpoints, print variables and stack traces.

Debugging using a command line interface like plain gdb has some advantages, but even old school people must admit that GUI comes in handy. So, as a last advise, after you understand and is confortable with the gdb workflow, you can search for a GUI debugger or even a full IDE that will certainly make your life much easier.

Comment: " That is usually achieved by running" Instructions for this library are [here](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/INSTALL.md).

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation(+1), but I have never tried anything of what you just said. It will take a while until I set up a ubuntu machine and go through everything. As explained in my edit, I'm using VS 2017 with Windows 10.

Comment: I'm back to this approach as the `vcpkg` only provided an old version of ffmpeg. Isn't there any way to build the cloned repository as `vpckg` does? Meaning to just give me the libraries, includes folder and the Dlls + Pdbs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vcpkg, open source packager, from github to build many open source projects including ffmpeg without any hassle. vcpkg has recently given support for non-windows platforms also, check it out.

A single one liner command on Powershell prompt `.\vcpkg install ffmpeg` ,is all that is needed. As usual the vs console project could be subjected for debugging also.

Comment: Thank you. I ll give it a go as it is is the easiest solution to try first.

Comment: Running `vcpkg` was really easy to build and now I have a debug version of ffmpeg with dlls and pdbs, but now how do i go about debugging?

Comment: Load a test program to check if you can call some of the ffmpeg libraries with error. You should be able to debug normally.